# The best OpenGL tutorial for a beginner - objects/light

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm looking for an OpenGL tutorial. Could you suggest something? I want to create some object, move them and give some light.

Comment: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with OpenGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239917/getting-started-with-opengl)

Comment: Here's where I first learned OpenGL

http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Comment: NeHe is pretty much outdated. It uses the fixed function pipeline which shouldn't used with modern OpenGL.

Comment: I can highly highly, highly recommend @R.MartinhoFernandes comment. It's using the newest technologies important for a beginner. NeHe is completely outdated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This Lighthouse3D lighting tutorial is excellent and not really bound to OpenGL.

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/?lights

If you have questions about context creation, event handling and such, read the basics here:
[OpenGL.org](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_%28C++/Win%29)